# Create Multiple Websites with One Shared Library by Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

What do I have to do if I want to use one library for many sites using Zend Framework 2? For example I want to have **/var/www/zf2-lib** and **/var/www/site-1**, **/var/www/site-1** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the library to your environments’ `include_path`s.

Comment: I know that I have to do something like that but, can you give me full information because I am not sure the all vendor folder should I move and where I have to change the path...and other small things

Comment: If you search “zend framework multiple sites” on Google, there are dozens of web pages containing instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to yo9ur ZF2 installation to the include_path inside your PHP config:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

example, change the path to the location of your shared ZF2 library below:

php.ini

```
include_path=".:/usr/share/pear;/usr/local/include/ZF2/library/Zend"
```

Comment: In config folder I have file application.config.php and folder autoload with file global.php. Where exactly I have to add this path?

Comment: edit your php.ini, this will allow PHP to find your shared version of the library..

Comment: I added include_path="/var/www/projects/ZendFramework/library/Zend" in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini but no result. :|